# Optionally pass argument to MSBuild from powershell

Tags: powershell, msbuild

In my Build.proj file, I have the following property:

```
<DbName Condition="$(DbName) == ''">MyDB</DbName>
<ConnectionString Condition="$(ConnectionString) == ''">"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=$(DbName);Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"</ConnectionString>
```

I have a PowerShell function as follows:

```
function Update-Database
{
    param(
        $DbName=""
    )
    msbuild $MSBuildFile /maxcpucount /verbosity:Minimal /target:DatabaseUpdate /p:DbName=$DbName
}
```

Running the function in PowerShell I get the following results:

- `Update-Database MyDB` : works perfectly
- `Update-Database` : Fails.  MSBuild does not use the default 'MyDB' in this case.  Instead it uses ''

If I modify this line:

```
msbuild $MSBuildFile /maxcpucount /verbosity:Minimal /target:DatabaseUpdate /p:DbName=$DbName
```

To this:

```
msbuild $MSBuildFile /maxcpucount /verbosity:Minimal /target:DatabaseUpdate
```

Running "UpdateDatabase" uses the default 'MyDB' and all is well.

If I want to have the option to use the default or pass in a new value, do I have to wrap the whole `msbuild...` command in an `if` `else`? or is there a way to conditionally pass in the argument?

**UPDATE**

I am trying to avoid setting the default in the ps function.  Basically I want to emulate this behaviour without the if:

```
function Update-Database
{
    param(
        $DbName=""
    )
    if($DbName -eq "")
    {
        msbuild $MSBuildFile /maxcpucount /verbosity:Minimal /target:DatabaseUpdate
    }
    else
    {
        msbuild  $MSBuildFile /maxcpucount /verbosity:Minimal /target:DatabaseUpdate /p:DbName=$DbName
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have to mix them? Why can't you, for example, define $DBName='MyDB' in the Update-Database?

Comment: You script right now is working by design. If dbname is blank you want it to omit that switch on msbuild. Is that correct?

Comment: Do you want the default to always be MyDB? in which case you just need to change the line `$DbName=""` to `$DbName="MyDB"` which is what will be used if no parameter is passed

Comment: I am trying to avoid setting the default in the ps function.  See Update section above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property you specify in the command line becomes a [global property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171458.aspx), which will take precedence over what's specified in the file. You can define a new property instead to avoid this behavior, like this:

```
<_DbName>$(DbName)</DbName>
<_DbName Condition="$(_DbName) == ''">MyDB</_DbName>
<ConnectionString Condition="$(ConnectionString) == ''">"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=$(_DbName);Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"</ConnectionString>
```

Answer (score 1):

While a great answer has already been identified, an alternative would be to use Invoke-Expression in powershell and dynamically build the msbuild cmd you want to run.  I have a gist on GitHub with an example (you could easily alter it to accommodate the optional db name:

https://gist.github.com/nnieslan/c631add56c5f7f3e7d6e#file-build-functions-ps1

Comment: Nice! This will come in handy in the future.  Thanks